# Phonegap Jquery Mobile Applications crash on Blackberry device but work on the simulator

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, blackberry, crash

I have a Jquery Mobile Application that uses:-
 - JQM (1.3.1)
 - Jquery (1.9.1)
 - Phonegap (2.8.0)

The application crashes on the Blackberry device after the splash screen loads, but, the **same** application works great on the blackberry simulators.

The application loads and works fine when the **cordova.js** file *is not linked correctly*. The app crashes when the **cordova.js** file *is linked correctly*, it simply closes.

Can anyone please tell me what the issue might be if you have faced it.

Thanks a million

Comment: Could you define "linked correctly"?

Comment: By linked I meant the path to cordova.js mentioned in the <script> tag. Eg: <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/cordova.js"></script>